# Subset of data based on conditions

Tags: r, conditional-statements, subset

I have researched the site but found replies that do not answer the question at 100%. I have a `data_frame` of 258 observations for 50 variables (sampled here):

```
pdis_reel   distance    corde   date_course spe ssp code_hippo  libel_hippo
3000    3000    G   25/03/15    T   A   1303    Marseille-BorÃ©ly
2625    2625    D   18/03/15    T   A   4701    Agen
2950    2925    G   17/02/15    T   A   601 Cagnes-sur-Mer
2675    2650    G   19/01/15    T   A   1302    Marseille-Vivaux
2650    2650    G   29/11/14    T   A   1302    Marseille-Vivaux
3250    3225    D   09/11/14    T   A   4203    Saint-Galmier
3025    3000    G   29/10/14    T   A   1303    Marseille-BorÃ©ly
2625    2600    D   04/10/14    T   A   303 Moulins
2875    2850    G   28/09/14    T   A   6901    Lyon-Parilly
2600    2600    D   10/09/14    T   A   8404    Cavaillon
4175    4150    D   06/09/14    T   A   7513    Vichy
2675    2675    G   17/08/14    T   A   102 Divonne-les-Bains
2700    2700    D   03/08/14    T   A   7301    Aix-les-Bains
2875    2850    G   04/07/14    T   A   4201    Feurs
2300    2300    G   21/05/14    T   A   1303    Marseille-BorÃ©ly
2650    2650    D   03/05/14    T   A   8301    HyÃ¨res
2650    2650    D   27/04/14    T   A   401 Oraison
2850    2850    G   22/04/14    T   A   6901    Lyon-Parilly
```

I'd like to extract all rows that nearest match conditions such as:

```
centpoourcent<- subset(data_frame, corde=="D" & pdis_reel==2900+-200)
```

when I look at centpourcent it has 258 rows and 0 column why?

Also, I am not clear on why exactly it is not recommended to use `subset()` in a script or program.

Comment: Is your condition meant to be `corde=="D" & pdis_reel > 2700 & pdis_reel < 3100` ?

Comment: right but I still get "data frame with 0 columns and 258 rows" for centpourcent...

Comment: Then no row in your data matches that condition. As simple as that. Unless you are looking for an *OR* statment, such as `subset(data_frame, corde=="D" | (pdis_reel > 2700 & pdis_reel < 3100))` maybe?

Comment: sorry mispelling error. Thank you.

Comment: It's not a typo, rather not understanding R syntax properly IMO

Comment: right, srry for being new but I will stick it out despite such uncalled for comment, besides +- would be a nice shorthand. Nonetheless, it is a typo because I was checking centpourcent, overlooking the fact I had sent data to centpoourcent...

Answer (score 1):

(As per request) I'll try to explain a bit what with wrong with your code.

When doing something like *2900+-200*, you  are basically telling R

1. Take the number from LHS
2. Add it to the *minus* of the number on the RHS number

In other words: *2900 - 200 = 2700*. This *isn't* the way to specify ranges in R

Consider the following example data

```
set.seed(123)
test <- sample(150, 20, replace  = TRUE)
```

Lets say our condition is *test == 60+-20*

We can do either

```
test[test >= 40 & test <= 80]
## [1] 44 62 80 69 69 50
```

Or

```
between <- function(x, upper, lower) x[x >= upper & x <= lower]
between(test, 40, 80)
## [1] 44 62 80 69 69 50
```

Or

```
'%between%' <- function(x, y) x[x >= y[1] & x <= y[2]]
test %between% c(40, 80)
## [1] 44 62 80 69 69 50
```

Or just load the `dplyr` or `data.table` package which have the same functions

Comment: Thank you David, I like the function versions best as they seem more flexible to use. I'll try to take a run at dates next. I want to take the newest date of my record set (max()), subtract 45 days from it (-45) and filter my data frame retaining only rows within that range.